# How to add ::-webkit-scrollbar pseudo element in Chakra UI element? (React)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm working with Chakra UI and i needed to customize the scrollbar style using the css pseudo element `::-webkit-scrollbar`, but Chakra UI doesn't seen to have this pseudo element and a I don't know where I can style this specific component without creating a global css class.

Here is a sample of my code:

```html
<Box
  overflowX="auto"
  maxW="100vw"
  h="100%"
  whiteSpace="nowrap"
  pb="17px"
  color="white"
  px="32px"
  // the ::-webkit-scrollbar property should goes here
>
  <!-- content -->
</Box>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try css prop:

```
<Box
  overflowY="auto"
  css={{
    '&::-webkit-scrollbar': {
      width: '4px',
    },
    '&::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
      width: '6px',
    },
    '&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
      background: scrollbarColor,
      borderRadius: '24px',
    },
  }}
>
```

Comment: Do you know how to add `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal`, cannot figure out what rules chakra is using internally for pseudo css.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful for me. 

Answer (score 6):

Use Chakra `sx` prop here.

```js
<Box
  overflowX="auto"
  maxW="100vw"
  h="100%"
  whiteSpace="nowrap"
  pb="17px"
  color="white"
  px="32px"
  sx={
     { 
    '::-webkit-scrollbar':{
           display:'none'
       }
    }
  }
>
  <!-- content -->
</Box>
```

To know more about Chakra `sx` prop, refer [docs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/the-sx-prop)

Answer (score 2):

> It worked for me you can use overflow="scroll" and with this the prop sx={}

```
<Flex
    mt="20px"
    overflow="scroll"
    sx={{
      "::-webkit-scrollbar": {
        display: "none",
      },
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

its not gonna work with just css you need to __css

```
<Box
  overflowY="auto"
  __css={{
        '&::-webkit-scrollbar': {
          w: '2',
        },
        '&::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
          w: '6',
        },
        '&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
          borderRadius: '10',
          bg: `gray.100`,
        },
      }}
>
```